# Need help reinstalling GRUB from Live CD

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

In Live CD I went in the terminal and when I do `sudo update-grub` it responds

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)
```

Here's the breakdown of my drive:

```
sda1 - vfat - Windows 7: FAT32
sda2 - 
sda3 - nfs - Windows Vista/7: NTFS - Windows 7
sda3/Wubi: - 
sda4 - Grub2
sda5 - Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
sda6 - 
sda7 - 
sda8 - BIOS Boot Partition
```

Also at the top of the page it states :

```
=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda
```

Any and all help is appreciated and welcomed.

When my computer boots, it goes into GRUB and has the options for Windows 7 and Windows Memory Test but no option for Ubuntu. I want to run a dual-boot through it.

Comment: Hm..., what do you mean by "sda4 - Grub2"? What's Grub2 doing on a separate partition? Any particular reason it's there? Is it really there? By the way, [this is the way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) to reinstall GRUB. Do not hesitate to ask if you need help with that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to repair grub from the LiveCD you need to chroot into the filesystem on the hard drive, otherwise it will try to repair the filesystem on the CD - hence the errors.

This question has already been answered here:

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)